# Oracle 19c with SAP System - ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified For Physical Standby

Tags: oracle, log, dataguard, standby, oracle-19c

Oracle 19c + SAP system. On primary side I have a problem when transporting logs to Data Guard side.

Outputs from primary side:

```
SQL> select status, error from v$archive_dest where dest_id=2;                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                    
STATUS    ERROR                                                                                                                                                                                     
--------- -----------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                         
ERROR     ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


SQL> show parameter log_archive_dest_2

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
log_archive_dest_2                   string      SERVICE=DRSIDE NOAFFIRM ASYNC V
                                                 ALID_FOR=(ONLINE_LOGFILES,PRIM
                                                 ARY_ROLE) DB_UNIQUE_NAME=DRSIDE

SQL> show parameter log_archive_dest_state_2                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                    
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE                                                                                                                                              
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------                                                                                                                     
log_archive_dest_state_2             string      ENABLE
```

Alert log:

> TT00 (PID: a number): Error 12154 received logging on to the standby
> 2021-02-20T15:48:51.144500+03:00
> TT00 (PID: a number): Error 12154 received logging on to the standby
> 2021-02-20T15:53:51.946941+03:00
> TT00 (PID: a number): Error 12154 received logging on to the standby
> 2021-02-20T15:58:52.744327+03:00
> TT00 (PID: a number): Error 12154 received logging on to the standby
> 2021-02-20T16:03:53.549161+03:00
> TT00 (PID: a number): Error 12154 received logging on to the standby

I did not make any changes to the tnsnames.ora or listener.ora files.

Edit: I tried to set log_archive_dest_2, I tried to send tnsping (successfully works from primary to disaster and disaster to primary), I tried copying passwordfile from primary to disaster. None of them worked.

Best regards,

Comment: And what did you discover when you googled 'ORA-12154'?

Comment: Hi @EdStevens, It's all about tnsnames.ora. I checked and it looks like true. I can send tnsping.

Comment: from which machine did you issue a _successful_ tnsping?

Comment: @EdStevens from primary side to disaster side.

Comment: @EdStevens I checked from disaster side to primary side too. It was successful.

Comment: What do you have for FAL_SERVER and FAL_CLIENT in each of the databases?

Comment: On primary side: FAL_CLIENT: PROD.WORLD and FAL_SERVER: DRSIDE.WORLD.
On disaster side: FAL_CLIENT: DRSIDE.WORLD and FAL_SERVER: PROD.WORLD.

Comment: It's been a number of years since I last set up a DG, but I believe that FAL_CLIENT and FAL_SERVER is where you specify the tns net service name - tnsnames.ora entry.  Take a look at https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/data-guard-setup-11gr2

Comment: @EdStevens I also used this document. My DG is still using pfile. Does this affect the situation?

Comment: I can't imagine that using a pfile would be involved, but on the other hand, I see no reason to be using a pfile over an spfile.  Bottom line is this:  tnsnames.ora is no magic in itself.  There is something in your db / DG config that tells the db what entry in the tnsnames that it is supposed to use.  And your current error message says, definitevely, that that reference in the config does not find a matching entry in tnsnames.ora.

Comment: @EdStevens Actually I started it with spfile but 2 days ago someones started it with pfile.  Anyway, this is unimportant. I found the solution. This is an SAP system and primary database should be started with ora<SID> user. But the last restart, I used oracle OS user. See the solution, https://answers.sap.com/questions/8049798/unable-to-ship-redo-logs-to-standby-db-oracle-data.html